# Почему слайдер не работает во всех браузерах?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Использую версию 5.2

Слайдер работает в Opera, Firefox, Firefoxdev и даже в Explorer, но вот в Ghrome и M.Edge - только картинка не из бд!

Кеш чистился.
В Ghrome ошибок вообще нет

В MEdge в консоли 2:
HTML1300: Произошел переход.
site.loc (1,1)

HTML1521: Непредвиденный тег "/body>" или конец файла. Все открытые элементы должны быть закрыты до окончания документа.
site.loc (549,5)

site.blade.php (полностью)

https://pastebin.com/WnKPgKeL

Что не так с тэгом body? И что за переход?

Секция body

```js
<!-- START BODY -->
    <body class="no_js responsive {{ (Route::currentRouteName() ==  'home') || (Route::currentRouteName() == 'portfolios.index') || (Route::currentRouteName() == 'portfolios.show') ? 'page-template-home-php' : ''}} stretched">
        
        <!-- START BG SHADOW -->
        <div class="bg-shadow">
            
            <!-- START WRAPPER -->
            <div id="wrapper" class="group">
                
                <!-- START HEADER -->
                <div id="header" class="group">
                    
                    <div class="group inner">
                        
                        <!-- START LOGO -->
                        <div id="logo" class="group">
                            <a href="index.html" title="Pink Rio"><img src="{{ asset(config('settings.theme')) }}/images/logo.png" title="Pink Rio" alt="Pink Rio" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END LOGO -->
                        
                        <div id="sidebar-header" class="group">
                            <div class="widget-first widget yit_text_quote">
                                <blockquote class="text-quote-quote">&#8220;The caterpillar does all the work but the butterfly gets all the publicity.&#8221;</blockquote>
                                <cite class="text-quote-author">George Carlin</cite>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearer"></div>
                        
                        <hr />
                        
                        <!-- START MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                        @yield('navigation')
                        <!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                        <div id="header-shadow"></div>
                        <div id="menu-shadow"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <!-- END HEADER -->
                
                <!-- START SLIDER -->
          
          @yield('slider')
          
          <div class="wrap_result"></div>
          
          
          @if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'portfolios.index')
          <!-- START PAGE META -->
          <div id="page-meta">
              <div class="inner group">
                  <h3>Welcome to my portfolio page</h3>
                  <h4>... i hope you enjoy my works</h4>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END PAGE META -->
          @endif
          
          @if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'contacts')
          <!-- START PAGE META -->
            <div id="page-meta">
                <div class="inner group">
                    <h3>...Say Hello! :)</h3>
                    <h4>Get in touch with Pink Rio team</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE META -->
          @endif
          
        
        <!-- START PRIMARY -->
        <div id="primary" class="sidebar-{{ isset($bar) ? $bar : 'no'}}">
            <div class="inner group">
                <!-- START CONTENT -->
                 @yield('content')
                <!-- END CONTENT -->
                <!-- START SIDEBAR -->
                 @yield('bar')
                <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
                <!-- START EXTRA CONTENT -->
                <!-- END EXTRA CONTENT -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PRIMARY -->
        
        <!-- START COPYRIGHT -->
                
                @yield('footer')
                
                <!-- END COPYRIGHT -->
            </div>
            <!-- END WRAPPER -->
        </div>
        <!-- END BG SHADOW -->
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(config('settings.theme')) }}/js/jquery.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(config('settings.theme')) }}/js/contact.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(config('settings.theme')) }}/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script> 
        
    </body>
    <!-- END BODY -->
```

Comment: Если убрать `@yield('slider')` все корректно отображается?

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов те же самые ошибки

Comment: Значит, проблема не слайдере? Нужно локализовать проблему, удалите все `@yield('елда')`, постепенно добавляйте.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов проблема не со слайдером, но именно он не работает. ошибка с тэгом возникает при добавлении @yield('bar') что там не так не пойму(

Comment: Значит нужно смотреть содержимое шаблонов, где эта елда переопределяется `@section('bar')`

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов  в indexBar.blade.php добавил в конце dive и эта ошибка исчезла. Но к слайдеру это все не относится, он, по прежнему, не во всех брауз. работает.